# How to determine the active Tree Viewer when selection changed from one TreeViewer to other

Tags: swt

I'm sorry if this question is too basic

I have two SWT TreeViewer's in two different composites.
If i change the selection of a TreeItem from one TreeViewer to other  , is there anyway to clear the selection from earlier TreeViewer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a selection-listener to `treeViewerB` and clear the selection in `treeViewerA`

```
treeViewerB.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent arg0) {
        treeViewerA.setSelection(StructuredSelection.EMPTY);

    }
});
```